# can't update Ubuntu 12.04 LTS-output of sudo apt-get update and upgrade inside

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates, downloads

I'm having Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I'm getting an error while trying to update.
if any further information is needed, please tell and I'll add it.

Here sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade output together one command after the other:

```
itay_rabin@itayspc:~$ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                      
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                              
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]            
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg                    
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                  
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex            
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]              
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                         
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex              
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb InRelease                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [164 kB]          
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [3,285 B]   
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [51.8 kB]     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-he_IL                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-he                       
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [4,241 B]   
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [388 kB]    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb Release.gpg                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-he_IL             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-he_IL                    
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-he                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-he                       
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [6,732 B]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [131 kB]
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb Release                       
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [9,672 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-he                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-he                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-he                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-he
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-he
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-he          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games Sources
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games Translation-he_IL           
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games Translation-he
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games Translation-en
Fetched 808 kB in 13s (58.2 kB/s)
W: כשלון בהבאת http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: כשלון בהבאת http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
itay_rabin@itayspc:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
itay_rabin@itayspc:~$
```

Thanks for your assitance.

EDIT-OUTPUT OF UPDATE IN ENGLISH:

```
[sudo] password for itay_rabin: 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise InRelease                             
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                 
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease                                
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease                        
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease                      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                               
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg                           
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [72 B]                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg                              
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                               
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg                      
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release                          
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]            
Hit http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner i386 Packages                 
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                              
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner TranslationIndex              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                        
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources                             
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources                         
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb InRelease                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources                     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources               
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources                              
  404  Not Found
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages               
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex        
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources [2422 B]        
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]    
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources [14.5 kB]   
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources [2240 B]  
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [1941 B]  
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [13.0 kB]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-en                
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-en                       
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [1897 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex [72 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex [70 B]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex [72 B]
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise/partner Translation-he                
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Translation-he                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex           
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-he                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex     
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-he                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-he
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-he
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-he
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-he
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-he
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en [1045 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en     
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en [9472 B]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb Release.gpg                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb Release                          
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games Sources 
Hit http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games i386 Packages
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games TranslationIndex
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games Translation-en              
Ign http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb/games Translation-he
Fetched 96.7 kB in 14s (6576 B/s)                          
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
itay_rabin@itayspc:~$
```

JUST UPLOADING:
[image]

Comment: Please explain (if you know) how the text is translated:  כשלון בהבאת

Comment: Sorry, i'm running it now again with "LC_ALL=C" before the command and I'll edit

Comment: I add the english output. sory to be late, it's "New Year" ("Rosh Hashanah") evening today (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your OpenJDK PPA is not functioning correctly. Please open Software Sources by searching for it, and then on the second tab, disable the openJDK PPA(s). You may then use `sudo apt-get update` normally.

Comment: YAY! It has worked! Thanks man, you're great! and have a good year (: